# Having trouble reading decoded JSON in PHP

Tags: php, json

I am trying to send info over JSON using Application/JSON content-type, but it doesn't seem to be decoding right, as in I can't read any params via code. Here is what I'm doing

```
//input is json:
//{"userId":12,"gamemode":1}
$input = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"),true);
echo $input["userId"]; //--> null
```

and echoing the contents of php://input returns the inputted json. Doing print_r on the decoded json displays this, which leads me to believe that I'm doing something terribly wrong when trying to get the param:

```
Array
(
    [gamemode] => 1
    [userId] => 31323231
)
```

Comment: By input, you mean the body of the HTTP request?

Comment: How are you passing the input to the PHP script?

Comment: Before sending anything, console log it to make sure... Also specify your data type. Does it show anything when you `var_dump($input)` ?

Comment: @ODelibalta misread the json_decode :)

Additionnal test: what does a var_dump of what file_get_contents returns ?

Comment: Using `php://input` you'll get something like `var=%7B%22userId%22%3A12%2C%22gamemode%22%3A1%7D`.  Try using `$_POST` or you have more work to do.

Comment: @AbraCadaver when I do echo file_get_contents("php://input"), it outputs the json I sent in through the POST body. The content type is Application/JSON

Comment: The print_r seems good. Is there anything else between the $input assignation and the echo ?

Comment: @NaeiKinDus nope, the code you see is the code I have.

Comment: Maybe you have to escape the json string?

Comment: Have you tried to pass the string directly to the json_decode function? Maybe it has something to do with the input itself